# How to get Zookeeper to serve up an IP instead of a hostname for Druid

Tags: apache-zookeeper, druid

I'm not sure if this should be a Druid or Zookeeper question.

Druid uses Zookeeper to discover Druid nodes. In my setup, the Druid nodes are AWS autoscale instances and get hostnames that don't resolve via DNS.  So when Druid asks ZK, it gets back:

spanky-asg-druid-master-10-0-10-218.sandbox-foo.net:8081

Is there a way to either configure ZK to return an IP instead of a hostname or for Druid to ask ZK for an IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `druid.host=1.2.3.4` (using the right IP, of course) in the runtime properties of the Druid processes, then they will announce in ZK using IPs instead of hostnames.